# Quicksort implemented in shell script doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, quicksort

I am learning shell scripting and trying to implement quick sort using it.
But it doesn't work, actually it acting weird.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a data=()
declare -r size=10
declare -i steps=0

for i in $(seq 0 $size); do
    data[$i]=$(expr $RANDOM % $size)
done

function partition() {
    pivot=${data[$1]}
    left=$(expr $1 + 1)
    right=$2

    while true; do
        while [[ $left -le $right && ${data[$left]} -le $pivot ]]; do
            left=$(expr $left + 1)
            steps=$(expr $steps + 1)
        done

        while [[ $right -ge $left && ${data[$right]} -ge $pivot ]]; do
            right=$(expr $right - 1)
            steps=$(expr $steps + 1)
        done

        if [[ $left -gt $right ]]; then
            break
        fi

        temp=${data[$left]}
        data[$left]=${data[$right]}
        data[$right]=$temp
    done

    temp=${data[$1]}
    data[$1]=${data[$right]}
    data[$right]=$temp

    echo $right
}

function quickSort() {
    if [[ $1 -lt $2 ]]; then
        local partitionPoint=$(partition $1 $2)
        quickSort $1 $(expr $partitionPoint - 1)
        quickSort $(expr $partitionPoint + 1) $2
    fi
}

# involve the algorithm
quickSort 0 $(expr $size - 1)

echo "Steps: $steps"
echo ${data[@]}
```

I tried to log some variable but it's just weird I can't figure out what's going on. 
When I comment out all the code in the two functions and 'manually' update elements of data variable, it did changed.
I tried to log some variables and they all changing.
But the final output remains untouched.
Or maybe it eventually reversed all the flipping but I don't know.
I can't figure it out.

At last I compare my python implementation line by line. No mistakes. But it just not working.

Am I miss something?

Variable scope or something?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Well a cursory glance reveals you have at least one typo `rright` instead of `right`...

Comment: Also, when it comes to shell scripting: the first thing you should learn is *not* to do these things 'manually' unless absolutely unavoidable. In this case, for 'real' scripts you would want to use the `sort` command.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: There are a bunch of stylistic issues in here -- using `expr` is a code smell (it's *extremely* slow compared to POSIX-specified builtin math), and the quoting is wrong in several places that shellcheck (linked above) will catch.

Comment: With respect to tracking down bugs -- `PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` up at the top of your script will enable line-by-line tracing. Once you've tracked down a specific bug, you're in a better place to ask a narrow, specific question ("I thought *this line* would do X, but instead it's doing Y; here's the shortest possible code that lets you reproduce the problem yourself").

Comment: One thing that **is** an obvious issue, and probably the source of your bug, is that you aren't declaring your variables local. It's hard to have safe, reentrant functions without local variables.

Comment: Performance-wise, you should also get rid of other command substitutions -- `$(seq ...)` is slow in the same way that `$(expr ...)` is.

Comment: @user268396 sorry I did fix that typo but forget to update. I think it's necessary to 'to do it manually' or reinvent the wheel when it comes to learning. Thanks though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for so much advices. I will check them out. update later.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/3un68y for a version of your code that's been instrumented a bit (and had `expr` and `seq` removed so it would run within the time limit allowed by ideone) -- you can see that `$1` is always 0 when we're doing a swap.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for recommendation. I'll check it out later.

Comment: Oh -- and your `partition` function is called in a subshell, but it's trying to change global variables; that won't ever work.

Comment: @Cyrus nice little tool, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several smaller issues in this code, but the biggest issue is here:

```
partitionPoint=$(partition $1 $2)
```

This is problematic because `$( ... )` runs `...` in a *subshell* -- a separate, `fork()`ed-off process, consequently with its own variable scope.

If you instead return your result via indirect assignment, making it:

```
partition "$1" "$2" partitionPoint
```

and inside the function using:

```
printf -v "$3" %s "$right"
```

...to assign the value to the variable so named, things work much better.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x

data=()
size=10
steps=0

for ((i=0; i<size; i++)); do
    data[$i]=$((RANDOM % size))
done

partition() {
    local pivot left right dest temp
    pivot=${data[$1]}
    left=$(($1 + 1))
    right=$2
    dest=$3

    while true; do
        while (( left <= right )) && (( ${data[$left]} <= pivot )); do
            left=$(( left + 1 ))
            steps=$(( steps + 1 ))
        done

        while (( right >= left )) && (( ${data[$right]} >= pivot )); do
            right=$(( right - 1 ))
            steps=$(( steps + 1 ))
        done

        (( left > right )) && break

        temp=${data[$left]}
        data[$left]=${data[$right]}
        data[$right]=$temp
    done

    : '$1='"$1" right="$right" 'data[$1]='"${data[$1]}" 'data[$right]='"${data[$right]}"
    temp=${data[$1]}
    data[$1]=${data[$right]}
    data[$right]=$temp

    printf -v "$dest" %s "$right"
}

quickSort() {
    local partitionPoint
    if (( $1 < $2 )); then
        partition "$1" "$2" partitionPoint
        quickSort "$1" "$(( partitionPoint - 1 ))"
        quickSort "$((partitionPoint + 1))" "$2"
    fi
}

# involve the algorithm
quickSort 0 "$(( size - 1 ))"

echo "Steps: $steps"
printf '%s\n' "${data[@]}"
```

Comment: It worked and you are awesome! Please accept my knees! :) I need some time to digest though. Great many thanks.

Comment: What is this line does BTW?
`: '$1='"$1" right="$right" 'data[$1]='"${data[$1]}" 'data[$right]='"${data[$right]}"`
I comment it out, and it still works.
I don't recognize the syntax.

Comment: @EricYoung, that generates debug logs on stderr with your variables' values when the script is run with `set -x` active. Makes the execution trace easier to understand. `:` is a synonym for `true` in shell; it ignores its arguments, but you can look at what those arguments were in the trace log.

Comment: @EricYoung, ...btw, I went through and did a stylistic cleanup pass -- note the `[[ ]]`s being changed to `(( ))` when doing arithmetic work, thus allowing more natural syntax (`>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` instead of `-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge`, `-le`; and making the `$`s unnecessary on simpler expansion cases).

Comment: That's neat! I didn't realize shell scripting has so much fun. You really cheer me up. I thought shell scripting is the most frustrating thing to do, because I have tried to debug this script for a whole day... Great work! And all the best!!